# Taking the price of a entity which is selected from the android spinner

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am taking data from `responseJson` to load in my spinner which I have used in my app. I have successfully loaded the data to the spinner using the below code. My problem is each item in the spinner has different values, and I want to use those values to calculate the total value of the items.

I have a `textview` as shown below,

```
itemvalueTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemvalue);
```

I'm trying to assign the value of the selected item's price to this textview.

Code used to load data to the spinner

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {

            List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> extraPrice = new ArrayList<String>();


            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) {

                    JSONArray subMenuArray = object
                            .getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");

                    for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                        JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                                .getJSONObject(j);

                        JSONArray extraItemEntityArray = subMenuObject
                                .getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");

                        for (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject objectE = extraItemEntityArray
                                    .getJSONObject(k);

                            if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
                                    && (objectE.getString("Type")).equals("E")) {

                                extraDescription.add(objectE
                                        .getString("Description"));
                                extraPrice.add(objectE
                                        .getString("Price"));
                                Log.i("ExtraDescriptionPrice", objectE.getString("Price"));
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Loading the data to the spinner

```
extraDescriptionOneSP
                        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                extraDescription = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(extraDescription);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        extraDescription);
                dataAdapterExtraDesOne
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                extraDescriptionOneSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesOne);
                extraDescriptionOneSP
                        .setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                dataAdapterExtraDesOne,
                                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                this));
```

json response

```
{  
   "ExtraSubMenuCode":"L   ",
   "Description":"Add B",
   "ExtraItemID":19,
   "Type":"E",
   "ExtraMainMenuCode":"EBC ",
   "Price":30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the json to java objects into a arraylist with GSON. Then from there build the spinner.

Then on selecting an item in the spinner. Get the object from the arraylist and calculate the price. If it is per item then the best way is to create an method inside the object that calculates the price so you can call it when needed and set it to the textview.

You can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the objects for parsing. And then create the method that does the calculation for you.

If you dont want to use Gson then you can use the above code as you mention and create your own java class that sets the data and include a calculation method in there. And then call it and set the data in the textview.

Comment: I'm new to android so your answer is too heavy for me to understand. But I'll try to do that, thnx

Comment: Have a look maybe at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html for the parsing. Also Google will give you enough results. Good luck

Comment: I'll try and get back to you if I get any problem, Thanks a lot.